# multiprocess download limited by throttle

Tags: python, locking, multiprocessing

I have a 3rd party python3 module that downloads data from a source in the internet.
I do not have control over how this module does that (most likely just a http donwload)
I only pass some key and the module returns to me the relevant data.
There is a limit of 1 download per second max.

I have 10000 datas to obtain through this module for 10000 keys.
So I construct the list of 10000 keys, then map the list over a multiprocess pool (say 4 processes) and collect the results.
Each process dowloads, processes the data, stores to file on disk, then return status. 
Each process does this for each of the 2500 requests it gets to work on.

The assumption is that result processing takes some time, and while a process is processing, another could download things, albeit all is restricted by the 1download/s max.

The code looks like:

main.py

```
#collect the list l of 10000 keys
...
pool = Pool(initializer=initPoolProcess, initargs=... )
...
m = Manager()
lck = m.Lock()
lastQueryTime = m.Value('d',0.0)

result = pool.map( f, l )
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

the other file mp.py has:

```
def f(...):
     while (datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() - lastQueryTime.value) < 1.0:
         time.sleep( datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() - lastQueryTime.value )
     lck.acquire()
     lastQueryTime.value = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
     lck.release()
     # do actual download
     # process
     # return result
```

question 1: given this piece code, how do I test that my assumption holds, that I am gaining by parallelizing the task?

question 2: if yes, is there any optimization to have here?

regards,

Comment: Have you tried timing it? Using `timeit`?

Comment: So, even with multiple processes, you want an overall cap of 1 key per second (with 4 processes, each process would do 1 item per 4 seconds)? Or should each do 1 per second?

Comment: The really easy to way test whether you'rer parallelizing the task is from outside Python. Open up Task Manager/Activity Monitor/xtask/whatever and look at your CPU usage. If you've got one core going at 99% and the others at 3%, you're not parallelizing. If you've got four cores going at 99%, you are. If you've got four cores going at 3%, you don't have any CPU-bound code so it doesn't matter in the first place.

Comment: Meanwhile, a smarter way to parallelize the CPU-bound work would be to do just the post-processing in your process pool, while you do the download-and-put-result-on-queue in the main process. (If the downloaded files are big enough that the cost of passing the contents over a queue is too slow, stick them in shared memory—they're just bytes, so they're easy to share.)